# Why exactly does the girl cry at the end?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-unlikely-girl

In the 2012 French movie "The Unlikely Girl" the English character cries standing in a square designed by an architect she loves apparently but is she crying because of this or because of something the French sister character said?

Answer (score 1):

She is crying because she realized that The girl was, in fact, Cecile and that her family exiled her. Either they knew about the incest, or thought she was lying. Either way, she was no longer welcome because she was the center of a horrible chapter of their lives. 
The girl is crying because there is no way to vindicate the abuse and rejection of Cecile.

Answer (score 0):

She's crying because she relised that Cecile really was an imposter.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail for your answer?